# Bad Request when trying to add JSON body to request with RestSharp

Tags: c#, .net, json, restsharp

So for the last 2 days I have been trying to add a new issue on a github repository. This seems fairly simple. The [documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue) says to just add some JSON and then send it on its way.

I first make an issue:

```
        public class RequestIssue
        {
            public string title { get; set; }
            public string body { get; set; }
            public string assignee { get; set; }
            public int milestone { get; set; }
            public List<string> labels { get; set; }
        }
```

and then create a call using RestSharp

```
        string text = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(issue);
        string text2 =
            "{  \"title\": \"Found a bug\",  \"body\": \"I'm having a problem with this.\",  \"assignee\": \"octocat\",  \"milestone\": 1,  \"labels\": [\"Label1\", \"Label2\"] }";
        parameters.Add(new Param("body", text2));

        UpdateParameterIfExists(new Param("content-type", "application/json"));
        UpdateParameterIfExists(new Param("content-length", "1200"));

        IRestRequest req = new RestRequest(repo.issues_url, Method.POST);
        //req.AddJsonBody(text);
        //req.AddObject(issue);
        req.AddBody(text2, null);

        req.AddParameter("application/json", text2, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        req.AddParameter("text/json", text2, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        req.AddParameter("json", text2, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        req.AddParameter("body", text2, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        req.AddParameter("data", text2, ParameterType.RequestBody);

        await addParametersAndMakeCall(req, new List<Param>());
```

and then makes the call. However it then never fails to return a 400: Bad Request.

```
        {
              "message":"Problems parsing JSON",
              "documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue"
        }
```

I tried different bodies, post parameters and the example. None of them want to work. Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: Changed content-type and length on the suggestion of [Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33508073/bad-request-when-trying-to-add-json-body-to-request-with-restsharp?noredirect=1#comment54801384_33508073)

Comment: If you're sending JSON, shouldn't the content type be `application/json` instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?  Also, are you sure your content length is correct?  The JSON string you posted is well over 100 chars long even after accounting for the escapes in the string.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. No luck though :(

Comment: `content-length` still @ 1200. I think you can leave that one entirely out. Try doing the post first with something like postman. Might enlighten somethings

Comment: Why not set the `content-length` to the actual length (i.e. `text2.Length`)? That would eliminate that as a source of the problem.

Comment: That did the trick, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Rest sharp has a built in method for adding JSON data to a request:

```
public static IRestResponse Create<T>(object objectToUpdate, string apiEndPoint) where T : new()
{
    var request = new RestRequest(apiEndPoint, Method.POST);

    request.AddJsonBody(objectToUpdate); // HERE

    var response = _restClient.Execute<T>(request);
    return response;
}
```

Might remove some of the uncertainty with your call